# Get remaining characters for Azure Translator Service via API

Tags: azure, translation, azure-management-api

I'm using the Azure Translation Services and want to know, how many characters in my current limit/budget/monthly I used and how many are left (in a free plan e.g.).

I tried using Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates route from Azure Management API - but the translation services seems not to be listed in there.

Thus, how can I get those values of limits and usage for Azure Translator Service via API?

Update:
API function, that delivers many results but not the wanted one:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[ID]/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedStartTime=2023-08-01&reportedEndTime=2023-09-11&aggregationGranularity=Daily&showDetails=True
```

Comment: please share the screenshot of how you are trying to get it?

Comment: I updated my posting with the API call

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate, to know the usage you can check `X-metered-usage` in the response header